# How to use ReadConsoleOutputCharacterA in Forth?

Tags: winapi, console, forth

I use

> WINAPI: ReadConsoleOutputCharacterA   KERNEL32.DLL

which seems to work, but how to handle the in and out parameters? Especially, how to get

> **hConsoleOutput** [in] A handle to the console screen buffer. The handle
>   must have the GENERIC_READ access right. For more information, see
>   Console Buffer Security and Access Rights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hConsoleOutput` there is just an appropriate handle as is. Some usage example for `ReadConsoleOutputCharacter` can be found in `devel` directory (contribution).

Example of this API usage:

```
\ Global variables in dictionary space just for learning,
\ -- don't use such approach, especially in multithreading.
VARIABLE lpNumberOfCharsRead
CREATE lpCharacter 5 CHARS ALLOT \ buffer for 5 chars

: XYC@ ( x y -- c )
  16 LSHIFT OR >R \ COORD
  0 lpCharacter C!
  lpNumberOfCharsRead \ _Out_ LPDWORD lpNumberOfCharsRead
  R> \ dwReadCoord
  1  \ nLength  \ to read
  lpCharacter \ _Out_ LPTSTR  lpCharacter
  H-STDOUT
  ReadConsoleOutputCharacterA ERR THROW
  lpCharacter C@
;

\ test
0 0 XYC@ EMIT
```

Useful wrapper:

```
: READOUT-CONSOLE-XY ( a-buf u x y -- a-buf u2 ior )
  2SWAP 2>R 16 LSHIFT OR >R
  0 SP@ R>          ( 0 addr-cnt coord )
  R> R@ H-STDOUT    ( 0 addr-cnt coord u a-buf handle )
  ReadConsoleOutputCharacterA ERR ( u2 ior )
  R> -ROT
;

\ test
HERE 50 0 0 READOUT-CONSOLE-XY THROW  TYPE
```